# I have to delete all browsing data every time I login to admin

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I moved magento site from a sub-directory (http://mysite.com/magento) to the parent directory (http://mysite.com). After successful transfer I noticed that my site url does not have "www" So I added it up in the Database in core_config_data in base and secure url fields.

That is before base and secure url were: http://mysite.com

After changing it: http://www.mysite.com  (added www to it).

Then I removed everything from the Var folder and deleted browser history with cookies and all other information of chrome.

There is no problem in frontend of the site, although I am not able to login at admin side. It just returns me to login page without any error but with a url like this

```
http://www.mysite.com/index.php/admin/index/index/key/b4f1cd105c9623c8d313c41e5c59f5b1/
```

But if I clear browsing history and cookies etc all, then it let me login once and for second time if I want to login again, I have to do the same process again .i.e. delete all the cookies and data from chrome history and then login again.

I have browsed same questions asked at stackoverflow and some other forums but all suggests to clean up cookies. But I think already did that, did I miss something or need to do something more?

Comment: What browser are you using? I know there is an issue while using Chrome. Can you try Internet Explorer or another browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be myriad things, but I'd check that your cookie domain at

```
System -> Configuration -> Web -> Session Cookie Management
```

matches your new `www.example.com` domain name.

Comment: Thanks much Alan Storm :) Am really a fan of yours, read too much of your articles.